# device send data to php and php send it to device

Tags: php

I am newbie in php. Now I have written two php files( *receive.php* and *send.php*). And in android device I also wrote an app which allows to input a string and post it to *receive.php*. Then, I can use *send.php* to send this string to other device by GCM server.

Now I have a problem that after receiving the string from one android device, how can my server run send.php spontaneously? I mean, once one device post a string to *receive.php*, *send.php* should be activated to send this string to other devices？

Sorry for my bad english. I am really looking forward to your help. Thank you!

Comment: It's impossible to say how to "activate" your script without first showing us some code.

Comment: Do you want to run "send.php" file after run the "recieve.php"?

Comment: @HarshanaNarangoda yes,but I really do not know how to configure.Thanks for your help

Comment: I added a sample code

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understand your question, i think in *receive.php* script, you should check that once you have received needed data, then execute the code of *send.php* . By checking it in *if condition*, you can include your *send.php* code in *receive.php* script itself.

Answer (score 0):

First create a PHP File named as a **DoSomething.php**

```
   function Receive() {
      code to be executed;
   } 

    function Send() {
      code to be executed;
    }
```

Receive Function Include your Receive.php Code and Send Function include your Send.

After that Add following:

```
Receive();
Send();
```

Then it's finished.

After this DoSomething.php File Code Like this.

```
<?php

function Receive() {
   code to be executed;
} 

function Send() {
  code to be executed;
} 

Receive();
Send();

?>
```